# Asp .net core - Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

The site does not start on hosting with an error Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack' or one of its dependencies.

I use

1. ASP net core with target net core 3.1
2. ServiceStack 5.7.0
3. Hosting [www.smarterasp.net](https://www.smarterasp.net)(Windows) or [www.reg.ru](http://www.reg.ru)(Windows)
4. WebDeploy - Framework Dependent / Self Contained

Local(Windows) or Azure(Linux) start with out problem.
Help me please to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate, I think this solution should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826481/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-servicestack-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-s